# stdexcept vs exception Headers in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

From the cplusplus.com reference for [`<exception>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/) and that for [`<stdexcept>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/), it appears that `<exception>` is sufficient for exception handling in C++98 or higher versions of C++.

Why does C++ have two headers files for exception handling? How does this affect my development? Which header should I use?

Comment: By looking into the header of <stdexcept> I found the inclusion of <exception>, which one to use then.

Comment: Did you look at the pages you linked to? As they say, `<exception>` defines the base class `std::exception` while `<stdexcept>` defines the various standard derived exception types. `<exception>` is *not* sufficient for those types.

Comment: yes I did but couldn't understand which to use when. I know while defining my own exceptions I'll have to derive them all from std::exception which is defined in <exception> and while using standard exceptions like std::out_of_range I'll have to use <stdexcept>. Kindly correct if I am wrong.

Comment: That's right. Use `<exception>` if you need `exception` (e.g. for defining your own derived types); use `<stdexcept>` if you need the types defined in there. In general, include a header when you need the contents of that header.

Comment: Since you tag this C++11, why no mention of [<system_error>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/system_error)?

Comment: I've always thought that these two headers have particular bad, confusing and ambigious names.

Comment: @Cubbi: Presumably, because that has nothing to do with exceptions. The question is about the two headers which define exception types.

Comment: @MikeSeymour the header `<system_error>` defines the exception type [std::system_error](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error) (which is also used as base for ios_base::failure now). It works great if you need to throw an errno.

Comment: @Cubbi: Sorry, I didn't realise that was an exception type. Ignore my comment then. Presumably, the answer to your question is that the OP doesn't know or care about that class.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

- `<stdexcept>`: Defines a set of standard exceptions that both the library and programs can use to report common errors.
- `<exception>`: Defines the base class (i.e., `std::exception`) for all exceptions thrown by the elements of the standard library, along with several types and utilities to assist handling exceptions.

So, `<exception>` only defines the class `std::exception`, while `<stdexcept>` defines several classes that inherit from `std::exception` (e.g., `std::logic_error`, `std::out_of_range`). That is why `<stdexcept>` includes `<exception>`.

They are in separate headers because if you want to define your own exception class inheriting `std::exception` (and not use the classes from `<stdexcept>`), you can avoid unnecessary definitions.

Comment: The Standard does not require that `<stdexcept>` includes `<exception>` at all.

Comment: I didn't know that not mentioning that the standard doesn't require `<stdexcept>` to include `<exception>` would be so irritating. Nevertheless, in most implementantions `<stdexcept>` includes `<exception>` (e.g., GCC, VS).

Comment: @Puppy The C++ standard does require that standard exceptions derive from `std::exception` publicly. It also requires that `<exception>` defines `std::exception` class. You cannot derive a class without having its definition. Your comment does not make much sense.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: imagine `<exception>` includes `<exception2>`, and inside that header, The class `std2::exception` is defined.  Then, inside `<exception>` is `typedef std2::exception exception;`.  Then the `<stdexcept>` header includes `<exception2>` and it's classes inherit from `std2::exception`.  Since `std2::exception` _is_ `std::exception`, this still meets all the requirements in the C++ standard, but including `<stdexcept>` does not include `<exception>` or provide the identifier `std::exception`.  (Also see that `std::nullptr_t` is a typedef for an unnamed type in a header)

Comment: @MooingDuck I think that would violate the standard because `<stdexcept>` exceptions are required to derive `std::exception`, not any other class. `std::exception` can be defined in another header, but including `<stdexcept>` must give you `std::exception` as well.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: In my sample, they do derive from  `std::exception`, but via a different identifier.  I don't see anything in the standard that says including that header must declare the identifier `std::exception`.  The closest is that the exceptions in that header must derive from the `std::exception` class.  Which is not nearly the same thing.

Comment: @MooingDuck The standard says explicitly that standard exceptions derive `std::exception`, not an unspecified class.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: The C++ standard in _many_ places refers to identifiers as if they were the class themselves.  See `§2.14.7/1 The pointer literal is the keyword nullptr. It is a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t.`  However, `std::nullptr_t` is _explicitly_ a typedef of an unspecified class.  This clarifies that the use of a typedef to an unspecified class meets the same requirements as if the class had that name directly.  This means the standard exceptions may derive from an unspecified class that has the identifier `std::exception`.

Comment: @MooingDuck Fair enough. Athough, if standard exceptions derived, say, `std2::exception`, I don't see a practical reason why `<stdexcept>` would not `typedef exception std2::exception;` so as to follow the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 13):

One practical consideration is that `<stdexcept>` requires `std::string` definition  (exception constructors accept `std::string` and have `std::string` data member), whereas to catch and query `std::exception` `std::string` declaration or definition is not required.

In other words, `std::exception` handler only needs `<exception>`. The throw site requires the header of a particular exception class it throws.

Comment: Requiring `std::string` is definitely not the same as requiring `<string>`.

Comment: @Puppy In this post `std::string` and `<string>` mean the same thing - having to include `<string>` header. But I fail to see your point.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: In Visual C++, the `std::string` class is _not_ defined in `<string>`, and including `<stdexcept>` and `<exception>` does define `std::string`, but does _not_ declare or define all the other things in the `<string>` header: http://rextester.com/XYQ2391

Comment: @MooingDuck I see your point now. This is what I was alluding to: including `stdexcept` gives you `std::string` definition as well (whether by including `<string>` or another header).

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: You say you were alluding to it, but your answer says that it includes `<string>` specifically, and when Puppy said corrected you, you said that `std::string` and `<string>` mean the same thing.  I don't see how you were alluding to that, while explicitly saying the opposite.

Comment: @MooingDuck The link that you linked is unfortunately dead - and wayback machine doesn't have it. What was there and would you have another link for that content? Thanks!

Comment: @Ela782: The [regtexter](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual) link was merely a sample of compiler errors, not an informational page of any sort.

Comment: @MooingDuck Oh that's too bad, but thanks! :-) Was curious to read more about the "define `std::string` but doesn't declare anything else" thing - will have to search elsewhere :-)

Comment: @MooingDuck That's what you commented above 4 years ago.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Oops. To be fair, that was 4 years ago. :D

Answer (score 3):

*exception* is for the user to inherit and define their own exceptions.

*stdexcept* is for catching and handling the standard exceptions